# XmlDocument rearrange XmlNodes C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have an XML Document that stores all sorts of information about users of a system. Utlimately, the nodes that I am intersted in I hae outined below.

So, there is a user that has many user contents - I have included just books as an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <userProperties>
    <alias val="userAliasOne"/>
    <id val="3423423"/>
  </userProperties>
  <userContent>
    <userBooks>
      <genre>
        <book>
          <title>Dummy Value</title>
        </book>
      </genre>
    </userBooks>
  </userContent>
</user>
```

I need to somehow restructure the XML, using XmlDocument and XmlNode so that it matches the below. (userBooks to become root node but all contents of userBooks - /genre/book/title - to stay inside  userContent).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<userBooks>
  <user>
    <userProperties>
      <alias val="userAliasOne"/>
      <id val="3423423"/>
    </userProperties>
    <userContent>
      <genre>
        <book>
          <title>Dummy Value</title>
        </book>
      </genre>
    </userContent>
  </user>
</userBooks>
```

I've tried selecting the single nodes and cloning them, then appending the clone to the parent and removing the child that's no longer required. It became very long and convoluted and I couldn't get it to work. There must be a more elegant solution that I am not aware of.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you can use LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument`? It's a much simpler API.

Comment: @JonSkeet the main issue there is that the rest of the code, that I've inherited, is quite old and uses XmlDocument. I've seen how much simpler it is to use LINQ to SQL while searching before posting this. This has been bugging me for a while today.

Comment: Do you need to modify an *existing* XmlDocument, or can you create a new one?

Comment: It's an existing XmlDocument that is having the structure changed slightly. All changes but this one have been implemented, so it's the last hurdle :)

Comment: It looks like there are two changes here: 1) adding a new root element of `userBooks` to contain `user`; 2) moving the `genre` element into just `userContent`. Have you got *either* of those working? Tackle them as separate problems.

Comment: I haven't got either of those working. That's what I need a ittle help with.
The userBooks needs to be moved from where it is now, as it contains other elements (too many to list) that will need to then become elements of the root node. If that makes sense?

Comment: Have you considered using XSL? It's great at changing the schema of XML and is fairly well supported in .NET. That's if your able to in your solution, of course.

Comment: So if you've got two problems, you should ask about them in two questions - or pick *one* of them to fix first, and see whether the answer to that helps you with the other. (XSL is quite possibly a good option here, as Matt says. I generally find it tricksy, but then the XmlDocument API is pretty tricksy too...)

Comment: And actually, what you've described doesn't make sense anyway - you've said that the elements of `userBooks` "will need to then become elements of the root node" - but in your example, `genre` is in `userBooks` originally, but *doesn't* end up as a direct child of the root node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> userBooks = doc.Descendants("userBooks").ToList();

            foreach(XElement userBook in userBooks)
            {
                userBook.ReplaceWith(userBook.Element("genre"));
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for adding a new root element:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test.xml");
        var originalRoot = doc.DocumentElement;
        doc.RemoveChild(originalRoot);
        var newRoot = doc.CreateElement("userBooks");
        doc.AppendChild(newRoot);
        newRoot.AppendChild(originalRoot);
        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
}
```

Try using the same approach for "removing" the `userBooks` element in the original - remove the element from its parent, but then add all the child nodes (of `userBooks`) as new child nodes of the original parent of `userBooks`.